# Подписи к точкам на графике типа LineChart

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь сделать всплывающие подсказки для каждой точки на графике типа LineChart. Построение графика работает, но когда я пытаюсь добавить подсказки, сталкиваюсь с ошибкой. Ошибка возникает в строчке:

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data> dataList = ((XYChart.Series) unicast.getData().get(0)).getData();
```

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: class javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data cannot be cast to class javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series (javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Data and javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series are in module javafx.controls@11.0.4 of loader 'platform')`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что делаю не так? Спасибо)

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("T(P)");
final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
xAxis.setLabel("P");
yAxis.setLabel("T");
final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
lineChart.setTitle("T(P)");

XYChart.Series unicast = new XYChart.Series();
unicast.setName("Unicast");
for (int i = 0; i < p_Unicast.size(); i++)
unicast.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(p_Unicast.get(i), TUnicast.get(i)));

XYChart.Series broadcast = new XYChart.Series();
broadcast.setName("Broadcast");
for (int i = 0; i < p_Unicast.size(); i++)
broadcast.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(p_Broadcastcast.get(i), TBroadcastcast.get(i)));

lineChart.getData().add(unicast);
lineChart.getData().add(broadcast);


ObservableList<XYChart.Data> dataList = ((XYChart.Series) unicast.getData().get(0)).getData();
dataList.forEach(data->{
Node node = data.getNode();
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip('(' + data.getXValue().toString() + ';' + data.getYValue().toString() + ')');
Tooltip.install(node, tooltip);
});

Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);

stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Comment: поищи получше. Здесь один хороший человек выкладывал "обманку" как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка здесь:

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data> dataList = ((XYChart.Series) unicast.getData().get(0)).getData();
```

Вы из серии берёте лист точек, из него берёте точку и пытаетесь её привести к серии. Вероятно вы перепутали `unicast` и `lineChart`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)